# Adding app to Django

Tags: python, django

New to Django.  I have followed the tutorial and have `mysite/` where `manage.py` is located, and `mysite/mysite` where `settings`, `urls`, etc are.  Also have `mysite/polls` from the tutorial.

I'm adding a second "app" called `blist`.  Ran `startapp` and created the skeleton under `mysite/blist`

here is the `mysite/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
url(r'^blist/', include('list.urls', namespace="blist")),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

When I try to go to `localhost:8000/list` it redirects to /polls.  I know I'm missing something silly but I figured I'd ask you guys.

here's `mysite/blist/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

here's `mysite/polls/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

Here's the Installed_apps stanza

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'polls',
'blist',
)
```

Thanks,
Dale

Comment: Could you please show your `polls/urls.py` and `list/urls.py`?

Comment: you will want to make sure that 'list' is in the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py

Comment: On a side note, `list` is a python builtin. it is a bad idea to  use that for an app name

Comment: Yeah...I actually typed in the code as it was on a different system and I was too lazy to login and copy paste....it's blist not list.  I've corrected post...good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Ugg!  I figured it out.  I did the cut and paste thing from polls/urls.py and failed to change the

```
from polls import views
```

to

```
from blist import views
```

Sorry to bother.

Comment: You told it was a *redirection*. Was it the redirection?

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^blist/', include('list.urls', namespace="blist")),
```

You might want to edit that one, because it says

```
include('list.url')
```

In my opinion changing it to

```
include('blist.url')
```

and keeping everything else the same might the app run perfectly.

Comment: Please read [answer] - You should format your code properly and please don't use "txt spk" and slang abbreviations like 'wanna'.